# How can I look for a correlation between dependent variables in a repeated-measures/within-subjects design?

Tags: r, correlation, repeated-measures

I have a 2x3 within-subjects design, with two different dependent variables (DVs). I would like to know if the two DVs are correlated or not.

Here is an example of what the data look like, e.g. a data frame in R:

```
# Make some data:
set.seed(1154)

data <- data.frame(id=gl(10, 6),
                   factor1=gl(2, 3, labels=c("A", "B")),
                   factor2=gl(3, 1),
                   DV1=rnorm(60),
                   DV2=rnorm(60))

head(data)

# Output:
#   id factor1 factor2          DV1         DV2
# 1  1       A       1  0.255579320  1.72318604
# 2  1       A       2  0.133878731 -0.32694875
# 3  1       A       3  0.890576655  0.14834580
# 4  1       B       1 -0.007879094 -0.07145311
# 5  1       B       2  0.976311664 -0.40686813
# 6  1       B       3  0.701357069 -0.50813556
```

In R, I could do something like:

```
cor.test(data$DV1, data$DV2) # p = 0.048, significant
```

but there seem to be two problems with that.

First problem: the data are not independent (first 6 items from each DV come from the same participant in the experiment).

Second problem: we want to generalize from a sample to the population, so each id in the sample should just be included only once, e.g.:

```
# We want:
#  id  factor1  factor2  DV1  DV2
#  1      X        X     ...  ...
#  2      X        X     ...
#  3   ...

# So:
library(plyr)
data2 <- ddply(data, .(id), summarize, mean.DV1=mean(DV1), mean.DV2=mean(DV2))
head(data2)

# Output:
#   id    mean.DV1    mean.DV2
# 1  1  0.49163739  0.09302105
# 2  2  0.66030997 -0.09344809
# 3  3  0.38277688  0.20274906
# 4  4 -0.35217913  0.57308528
# 5  5 -0.13470820  0.26663012
# 6  6 -0.04756911  0.60406950
```

Now I can look for a correlation and the responses are independent, but I have lost the individual factor levels.

```
cor.test(data2$mean.DV1, data2$mean.DV2) # p = .15, not significant
```

What is the correct way to check for a correlation between the two dependent variables (using R)?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "first 6 items from each DV come from the same participant in the experiment".

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. The 'id' represents the participant number in the experiment. The first six measurements from each DV come from the same id number (id==1). The next six are from id==2 etc. This might be clearer if you output the whole data, not just head(data). Hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps another clarification: Consider the data were from a between-subjects design. Then one could just do `cor.test(data$DV1, data$DV2)`, job done. But that assumes the data are independent. And in a within-subjects design the data are not independent, so now I am lost and do not know how to analyse it!

Comment: Shouldn't you instead want to know the correlation between DV1 and DV2 given each different combination of factor1 and factor2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your request for the "overall correlation" may be asking the wrong question. If you already know that you have varied factor1 and factor2, the correlations you want to look for are conditional the combination of those factors. It is unlikely the independent variables have absolutely 0 effect on the dependent variables, so looking at the total correlation actually includes less information than looking at each individually.

[image]

```
  factor1 factor2      r     p
1       A       1  -0.67 0.034
2       B       1 -0.043 0.907
3       A       2 -0.366 0.298
4       B       2 -0.632  0.05
5       A       3  0.066 0.856
6       B       3 -0.276  0.44
```

**R code:**

```
set.seed(1154)

dat <- data.frame(id=gl(10, 6),
                   factor1=gl(2, 3, labels=c("A", "B")),
                   factor2=gl(3, 1),
                   DV1=rnorm(60),
                   DV2=rnorm(60))



out=matrix(nrow=6,ncol=4)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
cnt<-1
for(j in unique(dat$factor2)){
  for(i in unique(dat$factor1)){
    sub<-dat[which(dat$factor1==i & dat$factor2==j),]

    cor.result<-cor.test(sub$DV1,sub$DV2)

    p<-round(cor.result$p.value,3)
    r<-round(cor.result$estimate,3)
    out[cnt,]<-cbind(i,j, r, p)

    plot(sub$DV1,sub$DV2, xlab="DV1", ylab="DV2",
         main=c(paste("Factor1:", i),paste("Factor2:", j),paste("r=",r,"p=",p)))
    abline(lm(sub$DV2~sub$DV1))
    cnt<-cnt+1
  }
}

out<-as.data.frame(out)
colnames(out)<-c("factor1","factor2","r","p")
```